# Wrong font in PDF figure exported from Stata

Tags: graph, fonts, export, pdf-generation, stata

I have set "Courier New" as the default font for graphics in Stata. Then all the figure labels and captions are Courier New. Also, I switched the background color of the figure to white.

However, when I export a figure (correctly viewed in Stata) to PDF, the font in the PDF file is back to Arial, the default Stata font for figures.

If I export the figure to PNG or to EPS, the font is correct (Courier New) but the background is bluish (Stata default). Strange behaviour!

**My settings:**
**Edit -> Preferences -> Graph Preferences -> General -> Font -> Courier New**

**EDIT:**
Stata version 12.0, OS Win7 SP1
It does not matter how I export the plot - either "Save as" or via command line -- the export always ends up with incorrect font.

Do you have an idea where the problem is?

Comment: Seems off-topic as it stands. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. [Statalist](www.statalist.org) is more appropriate for this question but you would still be required to give more  information: Stata version, operating system, how exactly are you exporting, etc. See "Advice on posting" if you post there.

Comment: Here's a relevant Statalist thread: http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-08/msg00933.html. In short, one solution is to export using .ps or .eps and then convert to .pdf using an external utility. (I can't reproduce your problem with the blue background.)

Answer (score 0):

Font settings for window output and export of graphs are different. Options for ps and eps can be customized with `graph set eps` but this does not seem to be available for pdf yet. 
You can use `graph export myfile.pdf, as(pdf) fontface(courier)` though.